# large Navigation Bar backGround gets clear color when swiping back to root viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have used `largeNavigationBar` and it's ok until i swipe back to root view controller and large navigation gets clear color in a nasty way. Here's the code:

```
func largeNavigationTitle() {
   
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = VVUtility.navigationBarColor()
    let productTitle = request?.product?.name
    self.navigationItem.title = "\(productTitle ?? " ")".localized()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: -2.0)]
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = VVUtility.splashBackGroundColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: 0.0)]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
}
```

I've recalled `largeNavigationTitle()` in both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`

**UPDATE**

Here is screenshot of two states:

Before swiping: [imgur.com/a/ZcSOrov](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvWOf.jpg)

When swiping: [imgur.com/a/DYeeot8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3vg1.jpg)

Comment: Are you using ib? In that case check that the color is correct in your storyboard.

Comment: @andromedainiative i've implemented navigationController Programmatically not in storyboard

Comment: @OmidKia add screenshot for navigation bar

Comment: @a.masri 
before swiping back: https://imgur.com/a/ZcSOrov
when swiping back: https://imgur.com/a/DYeeot8

Comment: @OmidKia try to set bar tint `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red` and set `isTranslucent`  `false`

Comment: @a.masri tried that and changed the color of rootViewController's navigationBar into red

Comment: @OmidKia Is still same issue showing ??

Comment: @a.masri same as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should set your root View controller's navigationBar's colour to the one you wanted:

```
func largeNavigationTitle() {

    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = VVUtility.navigationBarColor()
   //add the two lines below
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = VVUtility.navigationBarColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    let productTitle = request?.product?.name
    self.navigationItem.title = "\(productTitle ?? " ")".localized()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: -2.0)]

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = VVUtility.splashBackGroundColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font : VVUtility.normalFontWithPlusSize(increaseSize: 0.0)]
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your code ?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Does your method largeNavigationTitle() is implemented in rootViewController ?

Comment: it shouldn't be implemented. i only need large navigationController in child viewController

Comment: Yes but if you are swiping back to your rootViewController, method is not called anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually your navigation bar changing back to the small bar mode on the bottom controller.

This is because your navigation bar is not translucent. This causes (by default) the content controller to stop at the bottom of the navigation bar. So when the navigation bar becomes small again, there is no content between its new, shorter bottom and the top of the view controller.

Your hierarchy will look like this:

[image]

Now there's a property on `UIViewController` that defaults to false. You can use it to specify that you want your controller's view to extend under the non-translucent bar:

`extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

This instantly makes the hierarchy now appear as:

[image: image2]

Now you should no longer get the gap - but you might have issues with UI elements going under the bar. You can handle that by using Safe area insets and tweaking your layout as needed, using `edgesForExtendedLayout` may also help depending on your layout.

TL;DR Use `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`